# jQuery with C# doesn't fire onclick event

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an ASP.NET application that also uses jQuery for modal pop-ups. If I put an ASP button (or image button) within the DIV for the jQuery modal, the "OnClick" event does not fire.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the dialog, you need to move it a bit for ASP.Net, like this:

```
$(".class").dialog({ 
  //options
}).parent().appendTo("form");
```

By default the [`.dialog()` moves the content to just before `</body>`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L76) which most importantly is *outside* the `<form></form>`, so elements within it won't be included in the POST (or GET) to the server.  If you manually move it like I have above, it'll resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default, jQuery places the modal *OUTSIDE* of the asp.net `<form>` element.

You can easily append it to the form like:

```
$("#your-modal").parent().appendTo("form:first");
```

And this should fix your problems. It's a common problem with jQuery/ASP.NET.

Enjoy